# date calculation after date to string aren't coming out as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the number of days between two dates. However the data came to me as text. I'm trying to convert the text to numbers but the calculations are not coming out right. (first line in sample output should be about 9 days not 79, etc throughout the output. What am I doing wrong?

```
symbol
, str_to_date(option_expiration, '%m/%d/%Y') as op_ex_date
, str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y') as date_date

,(str_to_date(option_expiration, '%m/%d/%Y') - str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS days2exp

, e. date, option_expiration
from extoptdata e
where 1=1
and str_to_date(option_expiration, '%m/%d/%Y') - str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y') < 80
and str_to_date(option_expiration, '%m/%d/%Y') - str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y') > 30
```

```
symbol,op_ex_date,date_date,days2exp,date,option_expiration
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-22,79,02/22/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-22,79,02/22/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-25,76,02/25/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-25,76,02/25/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-26,75,02/26/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-26,75,02/26/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-27,74,02/27/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-27,74,02/27/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-28,73,02/28/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-28,73,02/28/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-22,79,02/22/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-22,79,02/22/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-25,76,02/25/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-25,76,02/25/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-26,75,02/26/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-26,75,02/26/2019,03/01/2019
QQQ,2019-03-01,2019-02-27,74,02/27/2019,03/01/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATEDIFF instead

```
Select 
  DATEDIFF( '2019-03-01' , '2019-02-22' )
From
 tableA;
```

Results in

```
DATEDIFF( '2019-03-01' , '2019-02-22' )
7
```

So you have to change your query to

```
,DATEDIFF(str_to_date(option_expiration, '%m/%d/%Y'), str_to_date(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS days2exp
```